# How can I list all unread posts for all forums that have unread messages in them in Moodle?

Tags: android, screen-scraping, web-scraping, moodle

I am developing an Android App for a particular instance of Moodle. I only have student level access, so I can't modify any Moodle files. I need to to display unread posts on the app. I can go to each course's forum and check for unread messages but that would be very expensive since  I am screen scraping data off the website.

How can I display all unread posts from all of the modules that I am enrolled in, so That I only have to parse one webpage to get the information I need?

Answer (score 1):

If you have ratings on and want to mark them, you could use the [AJAX Marking Block](http://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=block_ajax_marking). If not, you could tweak the code in it to show all forums even if unmarked (edit query_factory() in modules/forum/block_ajax_marking_forum.class.php) and remove support for all other types (delete other folders in modules).

I'll try and make a branch that does this, but I'm working flat out upgrading it for 2.3 right now, so it may take a while.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have student level access your options are very limited. Presumably the site isn't setup to publish the forum posts via RSS. You only real chance is if you can subscribe to all the relevant forums, then you could get all the posts from your messages page (or email, again depending on how the site is setup).

Moodle forums aren't really real-time (by default the is a 30 minute 'edit window' before post notification's go out) so if you are only polling fairly infrequently then then screen scraping each forum page shouldn't be too bad.

Again if you are a student level this isn't relevant, but for others the now-official [Unofficial Moodle Mobile App](http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/umm%3a_Unofficial_Moodle_Mobile_app) may be intresting.